# InfluxDB 1.8 - SELECT exact

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to discern if it is possible to query InfluxDB to have an exact match on tags without having to first query InfluxDB for the `TAG KEYS` to generate my query.

Here is an example to showcase what I'm trying to accomplish,

```
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.10.0
InfluxDB shell version: 1.10.0
> create database so
> use so
Using database so
> INSERT cpu,cpu=cpu0,env=intg,host=is-nflxts101t time_system=13592
> INSERT cpu,env=intg,host=is-nflxts101t time_system=134
SELECT * FROM cpu
name: cpu
time                cpu  env  host          time_system
----                ---  ---  ----          -----------
1668608108642977000 cpu0 intg is-nflxts101t 13592
1668608113752018000      intg is-nflxts101t 134          # <--- We want to get this line ONLY
```

The goal is to get the final line where `cpu` isn't specified.

The naive query gives us the complete set of rows, including the one we do not want,

```
> SELECT * FROM cpu WHERE "env"='intg' AND "host"='is-nflxts101t'
name: cpu
time                cpu  env  host          time_system
----                ---  ---  ----          -----------
1668608108642977000 cpu0 intg is-nflxts101t 13592        # <--- undesired
1668608113752018000      intg is-nflxts101t 134
```

and while I could first fetch all `TAG KEYS` to programatically generate the query,

```
> SELECT * FROM cpu WHERE "env"='intg' AND "host"='is-nflxts101t' AND "cpu" = ''
name: cpu
time                cpu env  host          time_system
----                --- ---  ----          -----------
1668608113752018000     intg is-nflxts101t 134
```

in my application code I was hoping there was/is a way to express this psuedo-query,

```
> SELECT * FROM cpu WHERE EXACT "env"='intg' AND "host"='is-nflxts101t'
name: cpu
time                cpu  env  host          time_system
----                ---  ---  ----          -----------
1668608113752018000      intg is-nflxts101t 134
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or am I stuck with fetching the keys first?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample should be good enough to filter out null-value tag with other conditions:

```
    SELECT * FROM cpu WHERE "env"='intg' AND "host"='is-nflxts101t' AND "cpu" = ''
```

as for tags, doing WHERE some_tag = '' will match rows for which the tag has no value. (The tag value will still be returned as null in the response, though, not as the empty string, because internally-consistent type systems are for pansies.)